# How to insert json data in Tendermint

Tags: json, rpc, blockchain, grpc, tendermint

How to insert json data in Tendermint in order to fetch using Tx_search URL

curl "localhost:26657/tx_search?query=\"account.owner='Ivan'\"&prove=true"

Guys I see this example on every platform, but no-one talks about how account.owner is added

Help me with writing JSON object on tendermint from commandline.

Comment: re: how account.owner is added: It's right above the "Querying transactions" section https://tendermint.com/docs/app-dev/indexing-transactions.html#adding-tags

Comment: @insaneCat that's in go, but buddy I'm finding JSON to write from command line.

Comment: I am also finding it hard to understand the documentation, how is it added?

Answer (score 0):

https://tendermint.com/docs/app-dev/indexing-transactions.html#adding-tags

As documentation says, the tags are added in `ResponseDeliverTx`. The example there is in Golang. Should be similar for other languages.

E.g., in Javascript using https://github.com/tendermint/js-abci:

```
deliverTx (request) {
  let tx = padTx(request.tx)
  let number = tx.readUInt32BE(0)
  if (number !== state.count) {
    return { code: 1, log: 'tx does not match count' }
  }

  // update state
  state.count += 1

  return { code: 0, log: 'tx succeeded', tags: { "account.owner": "Priyal" } }
}
```

Full listing can be found [here](https://github.com/tendermint/js-abci/blob/master/example/counter.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can find the answer on the [official Tendermint documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/tendermint/v0.21.0/tendermint.pdf).

On page 17, there is an example POST using JSON - you must adhere to the `jsonrpc` format defined there, and make sure your `tx` field is base-64-encoded.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)